# how do you set interval to ajax call in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to create an ajax call every 5 minutes. I have to below code. Can someone tell me how would I modify this code to run that ajax every 5 minutes?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
     var seriesOptions = [],
        yAxisOptions = [],
        colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;


        $.ajax({
                    url: 'echo_file.php', 
                    datatype: 'json',
                    success: function(data) {

                        seriesOptions=data;
                        createChart();
                    },

                    cache: false    
                    });

       function createChart() {
    .
    .
    .
    }
});
```

Comment: Put it into a setInterval, or even better, turn it into a function that calls itself after 5 minutes.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

At the simplest level, put your AJAX call into a function, then create an interval:

```
setInterval(ajaxCall, 300000); //300000 MS == 5 minutes

function ajaxCall() {
    //do your AJAX stuff here
}
```