# Unable to update page with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to update a page with set of html links from another page every 5 seconds, but its not working. it only updates the page if i refresh it manually on browser. Please I need help

**HTML PAGE**

```
<div id="sto"></div>


<script>
    function upd(){
        $('#sto').html('');
        $.ajax({
            url:base_url+'process/ajax/get3.php',
            cache: false,
            async: false,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(resp)
            {

                //$('#sto').html(resp);
                $('#sto').append(resp);

            }
        })
    }
  setInterval(upd(), 5000)
</script>


PHP (get3.php - links generated from db)

<ul class="chat-history" id="group_history_2">
    <li><span class="user">Test Patient</span><p>ddd</p><span class="time">04:10</span></li>
    <li><span class="user">Test Patient222</span><p>ddd</p><span class="time">04:10</span></li>
  <li><span class="user">Test Patient333</span><p>ddd</p><span class="time">04:10</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you getting if you `console.log(resp)` ?

Comment: console outputs the html just once and doesnt continue

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do you set interval to ajax call in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529783/how-do-you-set-interval-to-ajax-call-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the callback function as parameter on `setInterval`

Like:

```
setInterval(upd, 5000);
upd(); /*Add this so that you will call the ajax immediately after loading and no need to wait for 5seconds*/
```

You should remove the `()` on your code.

Comment: O yes it now loops through in console. Thanks, though it no longer displays on browser even after refresh

Comment: You dont need to refresh anymore. You have to wait 5 seconds so that it will call the ajax

Comment: You can call it immediately by `upd();`

Comment: yeah maybe something conflicts somewhere but dont know why if I place the (), it will display on browser

Comment: how you mean immediately?