# Refresh a div or function data every 10 seconds using php

Tags: php, html

I wand to refresh my notification count every 10 seconds.

```html
<span class="badge badge-danger badge-counter">
    <?php getUnreadMsgCount($uid) ?>
</span>
```

how to run again and again this function to get my notification count
This function stored in another page

Comment: You cant do this with php. but you can set `setInterval` in js to request every n second. if you want to use every n minute. you can use `cronjobs`.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529783/how-do-you-set-interval-to-ajax-call-in-jquery).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do you set interval to ajax call in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529783/how-do-you-set-interval-to-ajax-call-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code

```
<div id="sample">Testing refresh every 5 seconds</div>

 I would take a look at this below as well, although it may not be relevant in your case.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval
```

Java Script

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
  setInterval(function() {
     var someval = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
     $('#sample').text('Test' + someval);
  }, 10000);  //Delay here = 10 seconds 
});
```